# Duplicate Spring Controller method @RequestMapping for Restful

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, controller

How to have same url for normal and rest/ajax request. I have the following code and my Ajax call always receives the normal html instead of JSON.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/{customerID}/site/{siteID}", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody Site getSiteJson(HttpServletResponse response, Model model, @PathVariable("customerID") String customerID, @PathVariable("siteID") String siteID) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
        return dao.getSite(customerID, siteID);
    }
    catch (NuviaError nuviaError)
    {
        response.sendError(500, nuviaError.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/customer/{customerID}/site/{siteID}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSite(Model model, @PathVariable("customerID") String customerID, @PathVariable("siteID") String siteID) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    Site s;
    try
    {
        s = dao.getSite(customerID, siteID);
    }
    catch (NuviaError e)
    {
        ControllerUtils.addError(model, "Error fetching site details: " + e.getMessage());
        return getCustomer(model, customerID);
    }
    return showSite(model, customerID, s, "", "PUT", "Save site details", true);
}
```

Even If a disable second method it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are not setting the content type in the response

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer/{customerID}/site/{siteID}", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public @ResponseBody Site getSiteJson(HttpServletResponse response,  @PathVariable("customerID") String customerID, @PathVariable("siteID") String siteID) throws IOException, InterruptedException
```

anyway reciving the Model model here is kind of confusing, and you are not even using it, so i would get rid of that too

Comment: I copied headers from, your example. try getting rid of model and take a look at the produces= which should be available

Comment: Sorry: in our Spring 3 produces= is not available. Sorry this was confusing.

Comment: Stupid question but how did u setup your beans? could you post your applicationContext.xml ? are u using <mvc:annotation-driven />
 ?